# Convert Hijri (Islamic Date) to Gregorian

Tags: python, date, hijri

I was working on a group project when we came to need Islamic date in Python. I found an extension of Ummalqurra but it does not work on Python 3.7.4, I would like help in this regard from the community to make a complete resource for Hijri Date in Python.

> I thought of converting some Java libraries to Python but how???
>   By all accounts this needs to be done so if anyone has an algorithm to it please show us or a pre-existing library that I have missed in this regard.

'The other related article on Stackoverflow is on that of Iranian Solar Calander while I want the Islamic Hijri Calander.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`hijri-converter`](https://pypi.org/project/hijri-converter/) has been deprecated and will not receive future updates. Please use the [`hijridate`](https://pypi.org/project/hijridate/) package instead.

If you are using the Anaconda distribution, use `conda install -c conda-forge hijridate`, otherwise use `pip install hijridate`, as per [GitHub: HijriDate](https://github.com/dralshehri/hijridate)

---

Have a look at the [`hijri-converter`](https://pypi.org/project/hijri-converter/) package, which helps in converting between Hijri and Gregorian dates using the Umm al-Qura calendar.

Answer (score -2):

Try to install it from the Interpreter Settings.

From the corner in PyCharm, bottom-right:

[image: try to install it from interpreter settings - from the corner in PyCharm- right down]

After that, on the (+) icon enter "hijri-converter" and click Install:

[image: after that on the (+) icon enter "hijri-converter" and click install]

It should now be installed:

[image]

Comment: The question has nothing to do with PyCharm. This answer is a comment to the other answer, which mentions _hijri-converter_.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34249491)

Comment: it's not about the pycharm, it's about i face the same issue while converting between dates, so tried to install the Hijri-converter but i got an exception 

our friend here asked how to convert and there was an answer for hijri-converter package which is helped me but as i said there was an error while downloading it that's why i told him to use the Interpreter